# Get reference of one Activity from another in android

Tags: android, android-activity

How can i get reference to another activity, because i have placed an `ActionBar` in main activity say `ActivityA`, this `ActionBar` is visible on all other activities as well, now  i want to access this `LinearLayout` and make it hidden from `ActivityB`.

I want to do somthing like this.

```
LinearLayout bar = (LinearLayout) ActivityA.findViewById(R.id.actionbarhome);
bar.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
```

What should be there in place of `ActivityA`? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can inflate and grab the Layout of the ActivityA and then use findViewById to grab the Required LinearLayout e.g. :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout ll_ActivityA = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_a,null);
LinearLayout bar = (LinearLayout) ll_ActivityA.findViewById(R.id.actionbarhome);
bar.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
```

Comment: second line                                                 `LinearLayout ll_ActivityA = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_a,null);` gives exception "source not found"

Comment: I used R.layout.activity_a as an example. You use your Layout and make sure its parent element is the same as the one on which it is being inflated. e.g. LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial in [the doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Removing) about removing the action bar for a particular activity.

Comment: I need to hide LinearLayout on ActivityA from ActivityB,i have not used default ActionBar as i am using Android2.2, the ActionBar you mentioned is for android 3.0 or greater.

Comment: What ActionBar are you using then? If it’s `android.app.ActionBar` it’s only available for Android 3.0+, and I have not found any other ActionBar.  If you just have a LinearLayout, I don’t see why it would be visible at all from ActivityB.

Comment: actualy i have a layout file which contains home/back button, i added this layout file to TabHost in main.xml using code  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/actionbarhome"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" android:background="#FFFFFF">  
          <include layout="@layout/action_bar_home" />
</LinearLayout>, 
In this way it behaves like ActionBar and is visible on all activities shown within TabHost. Now i need to show/hide this linearLayout.