# App Crash When Trying to Change textsize in textView by clicking on button

Tags: android, textview, menuitem

In One Of my Activity I have a Menu Option With Text Option When user Click That it redirect to Another Layout where I Kept Two Buttons one is **Plus Button** and Another One is **Minus Button**

When user Click that Button I want to Change The TextView Text Size of the BackStack Activity

Here is My Code Below When i click that MenuOPtion the App was Crash and it Report **NullPointerException** in Logcat

My Detail Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_activity);

 detailtext= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail);
 dbHelper = new SqlLiteDbHelper(this);
        try {
            dbHelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor=dbHelper.getdetails(sqLiteDatabase, selectedData);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {

            detailtext.setText(cursor.getString(0));
        }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 int id = item.getItemId();
 if (id==R.id.text_option)
        {
           Intent intent= new Intent(this,CustomSetting.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Detail_menu.xml

```
 <item android:id="@+id/text_option"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Text Option"
         />
```

CustomSetting.java

```
public class CustomSetting extends AppCompatActivity {

    DetailActivity detailActivity;
    ImageButton plus,minus,close;
    int txtSize = 14;
    TextView detail=detailActivity.detailtext;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_setting);
        plus= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.plus);
        minus= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.minus);
        close= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.close);

plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (detail.getTextSize() == 14 ||detail.getTextSize() == 15 || detail.getTextSize() == 16 || detail.getTextSize() == 17){
                    txtSize++;
                    detail.setTextSize(txtSize);
                } else if (detail.getTextSize() == 18) {
                    txtSize+= 0;
                    detail.setTextSize(txtSize);
                } else{
                    txtSize+= 0;
                    detail.setTextSize(txtSize);
                }

            }
        });
        minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (detail.getTextSize() == 15||detail.getTextSize() ==16||detail.getTextSize() ==17|detail.getTextSize() ==18){
                    txtSize--;
                    detail.setTextSize(txtSize);
                } else {
                    txtSize += 0;
                    detail.setTextSize(txtSize);
                }

            }
        });
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(CustomSetting.this,DetailActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

custom_setting.xml

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/close"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/minus"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/minus"
    android:id="@+id/close"
    />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/plusign"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/minusign"
        android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Change Text Size"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        />
```

Logcat:

```
   Process: com.example.aa.sidd, PID: 23413
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aa.sidd/com.example.aa.sidd.CustomSetting}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
```

Comment: Your `custom_setting` layout probably doesn't have a View with id `plus`.

Comment: No I have plz Check My Updated Code Thanks @1615903

Comment: What exactly is line 18 of CustomSetting.java?

Comment: `TextView detail=detailActivity.detailtext;` @1615903

Comment: detailActivity is null at that point. You cannot refer to that variable there.

Comment: Wow men i was just going to ask you if detailText is defined as static, if not thats your issue

Comment: How to defined as static bcoz i want to change the textview Size! the textview was present in My Detail Activity But in the plus and minus Button was Present in CustomSetting Activity how can we Declare static? @Nanoc

Comment: Well, instead of declaring the activity as static you could store the textsize to sharedpreferences and use it from there.

Comment: How can we Do it @1615903

Comment: By using Google and then finding this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Omg @1615903 i dont think that is going to work.

Comment: I am not Editing my question i just now post a New Logcat Error After Declaring Static as Nanoc said  @Yvette

Comment: Maybe you should post a different question for this new problem since it looks totally unrelated

Comment: Is there is any other Option to Change the Text size from Menu option??  @Yvette

Comment: can i edit this and ask here or can i post new question? @Yvette

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Display the new layout in the form of a DialogFragment. The idea is to show the increase/Decrease option in the form of a DialogFragment popup. you can increase/decrease size from the popup. Once the popup dismisses the selected size is set to the TextView in your Activity.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static int updatedSize;
TextView greetingText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    greetingText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello_world_text);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        mycustomLayout();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void mycustomLayout(){
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    PopUp popUp = new PopUp(new FragmentDismissHandler());
    popUp.show(manager,"POPUP");

}

public void refreshText(){
    if( updatedSize>0)
    greetingText.setTextSize(updatedSize);
}

private class FragmentDismissHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        refreshText();
    }
}

}
```

PopUp.java (custom layout as DialogFragment)

```
public class PopUp extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

ImageButton increase,decrease,set;
TextView sizeOfText;
static int size;
Handler handler;


public PopUp(Handler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}
public PopUp(){

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    getDialog().setTitle("change text size");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_layout, container, false);

    increase = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.inc);
    increase.setOnClickListener(this);

    decrease = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.dec);
    decrease.setOnClickListener(this);

    sizeOfText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.size_text);
    sizeOfText.setText("text");

    set = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.ok);
    set.setOnClickListener(this);

    size = (int) sizeOfText.getTextSize();

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id= view.getId();

    if(id==R.id.inc){
        size = size +1;
        sizeOfText.setText("text");
        sizeOfText.setTextSize(size);
    }
    if(id== R.id.dec){
        size = size - 1;
        sizeOfText.setText("text");
        sizeOfText.setTextSize(size);
    }
    if(id== R.id.ok){
        dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    MainActivity.updatedSize = size;
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (id==R.id.text_option)
```

but the id of the menu is display right as explained below

```
item android:id="@+id/display"
```

So I think it should be

```
if (id==R.id.display) //like this
```

Comment: Sry typing mistake now i crt it but still the SAme Problem

Answer (score 2):

Though this question already have accepted answer, but it is bad programming practice to have static control references.

Instead you have intents for data passing, so when opening CustomSetting activity you should pass textview textsize as intent extra something like this:-

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this,CustomSetting.class);
intent.putExtra("textview_size",detailtext.getTextSize());
startActivity(intent);
```

Inside CustomSetting onCreate you can do

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("textview_size"){
  font_size = getIntent().getFloatExtra("textview_size",<default_size_your_want>);
}
```

While clicking on + or - button you can use

```
font_size += 1
```

or

```
fontsize -= 1
```

When clicked on close button you can do

```
Intent intent= new Intent(CustomSetting.this,DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("textview_size",fontsize);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in your DetailActivity oncreate you can do

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("textview_size"){
  font_size = getIntent().getFloatExtra("textview_size",<default_size_your_want>);
  detailtext.setTextSize(font_size);
}
```

Comment: Thanks But i have a Doubt can i declare Int Font_size = 0; in global?? @Rajen Raiyarela

Comment: Why you want it global, font_size is activities local variable. it is global at activity level not application level. Also for declaration you can specify minimum size you want not 0.

Comment: My App Was Crash When i click Text option in Menu..Check My Logcat

Comment: it crashed while launching CustomSetting activity. Check @Yvette answer.

Answer (score 2):

Three things,
From your original question:
you would be getting a null pointer exception from attempting to access an uninitialised object. In this case an activity.

```
DetailActivity detailActivity;
ImageButton plus,minus,close;
/.../
TextView detail=detailActivity.detailtext;
```

And what you are trying to attempt is not possible in the way you are trying to do this. Please see this link from a well known android expert.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6693367/3956566 which answers a similar question here [Get reference of one Activity from another in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692412/get-reference-of-one-activity-from-another-in-android)

Another, possible, problem could be your resources. You are loading multiple image buttons, ensure that your images are not too big in size (bytes).

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aa.sidd/com.example.aa.sidd.CustomSetting}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class

See this question:
[android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512981/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-12-error-inflating-class)

Thirdly, as I mentioned in the comments, I don't think declaring members as static as a work around is a good idea, see here  [Avoiding memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)  Static members, methods and classes need to be used sparingly and with thought when planning any application. In any language. Well that's my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have some line in DetailActivity like

```
Textview detailtext;
```

change it to

```
static Textview detailtext;
```

then get rid of your

```
DetailActivity detailActivity;
```

and change the line

```
TextView detail=detailActivity.detailtext;
```

to

```
TextView detail=DetailActivity.detailtext;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are the second guy telling me the same, please OP set it to null before using it. anyway maintain a reference to a view its not going to harm a modern android device.

Comment: @Nanoc Check My New Logcat a New Error was Occured Thanks

Comment: Its a worst idea to store a reference to a Context or Activity and i can see it many times with no one complaining.

Comment: @vasanth that is a totally different error caused by your xml layout "custom_setting.xml" take a look at line 17

Comment: Is there is any other Option to Change the Text size from Menu option?? @Nanoc